# how to load pagnation with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i have this code pagination and this code for quiz after click to next saves session and header(location) to next page for quiz.

now i want to load next page without refresh page after click to input next load next page ...

```
<?php
   $cid = (int)$_GET['id'];
   if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = 1;
      }else{
        $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
      }
      $records_at_page = 1;
      $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `cat`='".$cid."'");
      $records_count = $q->num_rows;

      $pages_count = (int)ceil($records_count / $records_at_page);

      if(($page > $pages_count) or ($page <= 0)){
         die('No More Pages');
      }
        $start = ($page - 1) * $records_at_page;
        $end = $records_at_page;

        $next = $page + 1;
        $prev = $page - 1;

        $qui = isset($_POST['val']);

      if(isset($_POST['next'])){
        $tst = $_SESSION['val'] = $qui;
        $_SESSION['value'] = ($_SESSION['value']  +  $tst);

      if($next <= $pages_count){
        header('Location: quiz.php?id='.$cid.'&page=' .$next. '');
        }

  if($next > $pages_count){
  echo '<a href="result.php?id='.$cid.'">Result</a>';
  exit;}

    }
         if($records_count != 0){
          $ar  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `cat`='".$cid."' order by `id` desc LIMIT $start,$end");

       while($rowar = $ar->fetch_object()){
         echo"
          <form ation='' method='POST'>
          <div>".$rowar->question."</div>";

           $ans = $db->query("select * from `answer` where `question_id`='".$rowar->id."' order by `id` desc");
           $rowans = $ans->fetch_object();
           echo"
           <div ><input class='rgt' type='radio' name='val' value='".$rowans->val1."'/><p>".$rowans->answ1."</p></div>
            <div><input type='submit' name='next'value='Next'/></div>
          </form>
       ";
       }
       }


   ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! What have you tried so far ? We do not write whole scripts for you here.

Comment: i want just code for load pagination with ajax without refresh page just this

Comment: You'll have to look for yourself there are lots of tutorials out there. If you have trouble implementing them we'll help you then but you aren't gonna get an answer without trying first.

Comment: the tutorial dont work in my code I tried several of them

Comment: I want one expert in Javascript for help me please

Comment: Post the code you tried anyways you are never going to get an answer otherwise, we'll tell you what you are doing wrong.